# Hide subview(uitableview) when ever user clicks on uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, xcode4.2

I am having an `UIScrollView` contains many `UITextField` and `UILabel` when user start editing one of the `UITextField` shows an `UITableView` .

My problem is when ever user clicks on `UIScrollView` other than `UITableView` have to hide that `tableview` and when user clicks on the `tableview` have to show the content in `tableview` cell in `textfield`.

Remember ,`tableview` is a subview of `scrollview`.

I am new to this programming, please help me out of this.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not a Good User Interface.**

You should envelope your `UITableView` into `PopOver`. There is a Step-by-Step process given here : [How to use UIPopoverController in iPad programming?](http://iosdeveloperz.com/tutorials/how-to-use-uipopovercontroller-in-ipad-programming/)

**EDIT :** Simply use this method to show `popOver`.

```
- (void) showPickerPopOverAction
{
    UIViewController *pickerPopOver = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    pickerPopOver.view = yourTableView;
    pickerPopOver.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(300, 210);
    UIPopoverController *pickerPopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:pickerPopOver];
    [pickerPopOverController presentPopoverFromRect:yourTextField.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

It will automatically solve your Problem.

Comment: can you tell me how to do ?

Comment: Have you checked that Link ?

Comment: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: and             "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PopViewController", referenced from:

Comment: I am not getting you. I tried my Best to explain. Just read the contents of the link and try to understand what it says. If that's not enough do some Research or Googling.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideSubView)];

// prevents the scroll view from swallowing up the touch event of child buttons
  tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;    

  [ScrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

  [tapGesture release];

}

// method to hide SubView when user taps on a scrollview
-(void)hideSubView
{
    if (self.SubView.isHidden == NO)
        self.SubView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: it is not working .(when i click on scrollview other than tableview it is not hiding the tableview )

Answer (score 0):

Pop over is only available for iPad not iPhone or iPod